# Scala Run Command and Capture Output

Tags: scala, command-line

I have a string with the absolute path to a command:

```
val path = "C:\\Program Files\\Some Folder\\runme.exe"
```

then I do the following to capture its output:

```
path.!!
```

But I get an exception:

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program"

Is it because there is a space in the path?  How Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because there is a space in the path?

Yes

> How Can I do this?

Use the Java `ProcessBuilder` API instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `Seq(path).!!` if you want to continue to use this API.